# Sort 1TB file on machine with 1GB RAM

Tags: c++, sorting, memory-management, external-sorting

This questions seems easy, but I am not able to understand the real work behind it.
I know people will say, break down into 512 Megs chunks and sort them like using Merge Sort using Map reduce.

So here is the actual question i have:

Suppose i break the file into 512 Megs chunk and then send to different host machines to sort them.
suppose these machines used the Merge Sort.
Now say, i had 2000 machines each sorted 2000, 512 megs of chunk. Now when i merge them back, how does that work? Won't the size keep on increasing again? For example merging two 512 megs will make 1024Megs which is size of my RAM so how would this work? Any machine can't merge a chunk of more than 512 megs chunk with another chunk because then size > 1 GB.

How at the end of merging will i ever be able to merge two 0.5 TB chunk with another 0.5 TB chunk.. Does the concept of Virtual Memory come into play here?

I am here to clarify my basics and i hope i am asking this very important question (correctly) correctly. Also, who should do this merge(after sorting)? My machine or few of those 2000 machines?

Comment: You'd only run out of memory if you try to hold the file(s) in memory. Once you've chunked the file and sorted each chunk, you only have to keep one line of each file in memory as you merge/write them out to a new file.

Comment: Merge sort is one of my favorite algorithms. So simple to understand, and so useful.

Comment: BTW, it's possible to this using only 2 read/write passes over the entire dataset. (4 TB of I/O total) I'll skip the details as it's very complicated, but it uses the same approach as the out-of-core FFT algorithms.

Comment: You should be looking at using a better data-structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a theoretical way which should work. Say you've got your 2000 512mb files, ready to create one 1TB file.

If you simply loop through every file, find which one has the lowest FIRST value, then move that into your destination file, and repeat then you'll end up with everything in order. RAM usage should be tiny as you'll never need to open more than one line at a time.

Obviously you should be able to optimize this - keep the first line of every file in RAM as you go and it should be somewhat faster.

Comment: Beaten by 30 seconds - sounds like @David Schwartz has the same solution, but with the bonus of a numbered list.

Comment: There exists a better solution.

Comment: Each file must be then already sorted to easily find lowest first value

Answer (score 10):

This problem can be **reduced to a simpler problem**. This problem was designed to force you to an approach. Here it is:

- Pick up chunks =~ 1GB, sort & store them as separate sorted files.
- You end up with 1000 1GB sorted files on the file system.
- Now, its simply a problem of merging k-sorted arrays into a new array.

  Merging k-sorted arrays need you to maintain a min-heap (Priority Queue) with k elements at a time.

i.e. **k = 1000** (files) in our case. ( **1GB ram can store 1000 numbers** )

Therefore, keep poping elements from your priority queue and save to disk.

**You will have a new file, sorted of size 1TB.**

Refer: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/

**Update**

**PS:** Can be done on a single machine with 1 GB RAM with a better data structure

Merge can be done in less than **O(N) space** with Priority Queue i.e. **O(K) space** i.e. the heart of the problem.

Comment: very clear and good explanation. I was having some trouble understanding the solution.

Answer (score 6):

The short version of how you merge is like this:

1) You create a table with one slot for each machine you are merging from.

2) You ask each machine for the lowest entry they have that they have not given you yet.

3) You remove the lowest-valued entry from your table, output it, and ask that machine to refill the slow with the lowest entry it has not given you yet, leaving the slot empty if the machine is out of entries.

4) You repeat step 3 until the table is empty.

This allows you to merge from N machines storing only N entries at a time. Of course, you can trivially optimize it to hold M entries from each machine. In that case, you need to store N*M entries, and when a slot is empty, ask that machine for M entries to refill it.

Comment: Thanks David, my questions was little different. Sorry, i should asked in a better way. But "In Silico" answer solved all my doubts.

Answer (score 4):

> Now say, i had 2000 machines each sorted 2000, 512 megs of chunk. Now
>   when i merge them back, how does that work? Won't the size keep on
>   increasing again? For example merging two 512 megs will make 1024Megs
>   which is size of my RAM so how would this work? Any machine can't
>   merge a chunk of more than 512 megs chunk with another chunk because
>   then size > 1 GB.

That's not how a practical mergesort implementation works. The cool thing about mergesort (and related sort algorithms) is that you don't need to have the entire dataset in memory to make it work. When merging you only need to read into memory a tiny portion of the file at a time, which will be then written out soon later.

In other words, you don't need random access for mergesort. If it weren't for this nice property it would be impossible to [sort the data on tape drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives) with the technology available at the time. Tape drives are of course not random access media and RAM back then were measured in kilobytes.

Comment: So lets say i am working on two .5 TB chunk.

Now, I know that 1st line of both of them are smallest one (lets say sorting was by string length). So in memory i only have the 1st two lines from each file and rest of the file in meomory??

Comment: No, you only need the first lines from each of the two files into memory to compare them, then write out whichever is smaller into a third file. Although in a practical implementation you try to read as much as you can at once since disk I/O is slow, but the data will be on disk most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about a merge sort is that you don't need random access; sequential access will do. That's what makes it a perfect solution when the dataset won't fit in memory.

A single merge pass requires 2 (or more) inputs and produces one output. You just keep combining inputs into outputs until there is only one file left.

Comment: Thanks Mark. After reading "In Silico"'s answer, picture became clearer. 

You guys are awesome. Thanks. I still have this question?

So lets say i am working on two .5 TB chunk. Now, I know that 1st line of both of them are smallest one (lets say sorting was by string length). So in memory i only have the 1st two lines from each file and rest of the file in meomory??

Comment: @Leoheart, I think you meant to say "and rest of the file on disk". If so you are correct.

Comment: ohh sorry.. yaa, i meant the rest of the file on disk.. 
thank you